# Retrieving first part of two-part params[:id] in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, parameters, viewparams

I'm sure this has been answered before but I've looked everywhere, so I apologize in advance. When I run:

```
<%= params %>
```

I get back: {"controller"=>"spree/taxons", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"women/long-sleeve"}

I'm trying to access the :id in the show action of the taxons controller. I have:

```
def show
  @taxon_id = params[:id]
end
```

This assigns 'women/long-sleeve' to @taxon_id.

Is there a way to retrieve only 'women' from 'women/long-sleeve'.

I would like to render a partial based on this, something like:

```
<% if @taxon_id == params[:id] %>
  <%= render 'shared/#{#taxon_id}' %>
<% end %>
```

But instead of rendering 'shared/women' it's trying to render 'shared/women/long-sleeve', which isn't a partial.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want "women" from your params hash then you can do

```
@taxon_id = params[:id].split("/").first
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just split on `/` and grab the first element in the resulting array:

```
params[:id].split('/').first
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's always going to be in that format you can change your route:

```
match '/spree/taxons/:id/:slug' => 'taxons#show'
```

And your `:id` field will match correctly.